# Rails Routing Error? 'No route matches'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

So I keep running into the following error:

> `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}`

I tried running rake routes and I can see that the route exists:

```
 user         GET          /users/:id(.:format)       users#show
              PUT          /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
              DELETE       /users/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
```

But every time I try visiting the page `"/users/1"` (1 being the user id), I get the above error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's my `routes.rb`:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  resources :users
  resource :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]


  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

Here's my `users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Paper Piazza!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

Comment: show your routes.rb file

Comment: No, `/users/1/` does not seem to work..

Comment: Do you have a `users_controller.rb`?

Comment: Yeah, I'll just post that up too.

Comment: Is that the exact error you're getting? Could this question be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217093/rails-app-saying-cant-find-users-route-should-be-working?rq=1

Comment: I don't think the two are related. At least, the answer doesn't work for my case.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the server? Ones that work for me! If not as DVG said, what's the full trace

Comment: Do you perhaps have another instance of the WEBrick server running like the gentleman from [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10965608/567863)?

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing the typo:

```
root :to 'static_pages#home'
```

(rather than `root to:`), and moving it to the last line of the block.  And let me know if that makes a difference!

What's odd is that I built a fresh project with a routing file that simply reads:

```
RoutingTest::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  root :to => "static_pages#home"
end
```

When I ran this in the console, I got the same error you're seeing:

```
>> r = Rails.application.routes ; true
=> true
>> r.recognize_path("/users/1")
=> ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/users"
```

... but when I run the same thing in a slightly older project, I get:

```
>> r = Rails.application.routes ; true
=> true
>> r.recognize_path("/users/1")
=> {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>"1"}
```

So I have little confidence that what I'm telling you will make a difference.  (Aside from that, the Rails.application.routes trick is useful for verifying paths in the console!)

Comment: Be careful with reserved names.  Try not using static_pages and see what you get.

Comment: `root to: 'static_pages#home'` is the correct syntax,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I had routes that would just return the root page, but would show up in `rake routes`. According to a fellow developer for a specific namespace and for all routes the `root to: (routing)` must always be last. This is in contradiction to the Rails guide on routing (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) which says that any call to root should be at the top of your file. That was definitely not working for me. Interesting...